# Given a failed contract transaction how can I determine on which line of contact source code execution was fail?

Tags: tokens, contract-debugging

I have failed token transfer and I want to know why it was failed by reading contract source code. Is there any steps I can make to know on which line of the source contract code the execution was failed? I am not a contract developer, I want to know why concrete transaction was failed.

For example, how can I determine the line where contract was failed for this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x447b1c4ffd625601a55c0add8dde374d1d6fa3153b1e0e6babfd0dbe2cb90608

Answer (score 1):

From the error on EtherScan you won't be able to find the exact spot in your source code with an error, but these tips from their "Help" center might help you discover the error.

> The most common reasons an ERC-20 token transfer might have failed are:
>
> 1. The Token contract is locked (tokens are not transferable yet)
> 2. The sending From account has an insufficient token balance
> 3. Or in some cases the Token contract does not emit a Transfer event even though the balance is actually deducted (Not compatible fully ERC-20 Compliant)

Comment: I am sending some automated transfers and some of them are failed and some are not. I don't have a source I want to see whats going on during contract execution to know exactly what's wrong. Is there some handy tools other then etherscan for this kind of job?